# Total Goals and separated ones don´t add the same

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have created four goals. The total goals completions is 5,889. But on its right I see the fourth ones separated: Goal 4 is 343, Goal 5 is 2008, Goal 6 is 201 and Goal 7 is 40. It would have an add result of 2592. Goals 1, 2 and 3 are off. Why does it make sense the sum?

Comment: Have goals 1-3 been turned off for the entire date range your report is set to? In my GA the total goal completions is exactly the sum of the completions for the individual goals, and I believe that's how it's computed, not some other way that could introduce a difference.

Comment: Now they are ok, perhaps they were "hooked" at the beggining. Thanks :)